# Non=singularity of a "quadratic" matrix

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be a integer vector, consider the $6$ dim vector 
$f(x)= (x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2, x_1 x_2, x_1 x_3, x_2x_3)$.

Now take 6 vectors $u_1, \dots, u_6$ in $Z^3$. I wonder if there is a sufficient (and easy to check) condition that guarantees that the six vectors $f(u_1), \dots, f(u_6)$ are linearly independent.

For instance, is it true that if the $u_i$ are in (linearly) general position, then the $f(u_i)$ are linearly independent.

What happen in the general case when $u_i$ is in $Z^d$ and $f(u_i)$ is in 
$Z^{d(d+1)/2}$ ?

Comment: I presume that you have checked out yourself the case $d=2$, where we have $\det(f(u_1),f(u_2),f(u_3))=\det(u_1,u_2)\cdot\det(u_1,u_3)\cdot\det(u_3,u_2)$. Nothing that nice if $d\ge3$.

Comment: It is not true that linear general position is enough. The condition is exactly that the six points do not lie on a quadric and the general sextuple lying on a quadric is in general linear position.

Comment: I see. It is indeed not sufficient. 

Answer (score 1):

In the case $d=3$ the determinant of the $6 \times 6$ matrix formed by these vectors is a polynomial in 18 variables with 720 terms, each of total degree 12, and of degree 2 in each variable.  It does not factor over the rationals.  So there does not seem to be any simple characterization of linear independence other than that polynomial being nonzero.

Comment: I am asking for a sufficient condition, not a characterization. For example, is there a counter example to the condition that the $u_i$ are in general position ? 

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is the $n=2$ case of asking when the Lagrange interpolation problem on the set $\{u_\alpha\}$ is "poised" (I am using multi-index notation). See, e.g. the introduction to [Sauer, T. and Xu, Y. "On multivariate Lagrange interpolation". *Math. Comp.* **64**, 1147 (1995)](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2153487).

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the definition. But I did not find any good answer.

Comment: In the case you discuss, "the Lagrange interpolation problem is poised if, and only if, the node sequence...does not lie on a hypersurface of degree n...equivalently, the Vandermonde determinant 
formed by the interpolation points does not vanish." Of course the determinant condition is already mentioned in your question, but the other equivalent condition is the general case of what Torsten Ekedahl mentioned above.

Comment: It seems to me that that sentence refers to the case when H has 10 points (or the sequence of points is poised with respect to the whole space). Here we are talking about a subspace of dimension 6. 